# Querying to fetch relationship data in laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent-relationship

I am fetching post with the specific tag id and I have following code so far.

```
public static function getPostByTag($id) {
    return Tag::with('posts')->whereHas('posts', function($q) use(&$id) {
      $q->where('tags.id',$id);
    })->get();
}
```

The data I am getting is working perfectly so far but now, I want to limit the data. What should I do to limit data?

I have tried following:

```
public static function getPostByTag($id) {
    return Tag::with('posts')->whereHas('posts', function($q) use(&$id) {
      $q->where('tags.id',$id);
    })->take(5)->get();
}
```

But, it does not seem to work. Also, I want to list my post by according to latest date.

Comment: @Rwd Any example? Because I have no idea.

Comment: u want to limit datas of tags or posts?

Comment: @TsaiKoga I want to limit post coming in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to get post by the `tag_id`, you can just use `Tag::where('id', $id)`

If you want the latest posts, you can use `->latest()` method, it will automatically order by `created_at` desc.

And you want to limit the posts, you need to limit it in `with` closure:

```php
public static function getPostByTag($id){
    return Tag::where('id', $id)->has('posts')
              ->with(['posts' => function($q) {
                 $q->latest()->limit(5);
              }])->get();
}
```

Comment: It says, `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: It still gives all post in the tag.

Comment: @Eliesha I think you want the tag with `id`, you can just find the tag with its posts.

Comment: I want posts which have tag id, lets suppose is 21.

Comment: @Eliesha you can try my post, assuming id=21, it will find the tag id is 21, and get the tag with its latest 5 posts

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in the following ways:

```
public static function getPostByTag($id){
    return Tag::whereHas('posts', function($q) use(&$id){
        $q->where('tags.id',$id);
    }->with(['posts' => function($q) {
        $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->take(5);
    }])->get();
}
```

Comment: It says, Tag model does not exists.

Comment: @Eliesha You should add `use App\Tag;` at the top of the controller class.

Comment: No. I have Tag model inside Models folder.

Comment: @Eliesha So add `use App\Models\Tag;` instead.

Comment: No it is not fix yet. I am creating getPostByTag on Tag model itself. DO I have to add `App\Models\Tag` in its model itself?